# Not able to run applet in my IE8

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception

I  have a web page which In which I am searching for  a zebra printer by an applet.

The applet works fine on other system but not on my system.I tested the few thing about applet setting in my browser...

1. I Checked If applet is enabled or not by JAVA administrative window from control panel
2. I checked JAVA Add - Ons in my IE from "Manage Add Ons" option..

I am referring this link to solve the problem :

http://javatester.org/enabled.html

But this on line applet testing gives error..

```
ClassNotFoundExceptioln : Tiny.
```

It seems that applet is working in my system but it not able to retrieve class file from the server.

Do you have any ideas? How to solve this problem?  Is there any network or firewall settings?

Comment: What role does the "Tiny" class have in your applet?

Comment: *"Do you have any ideas?"* Post an URL where we can see the applet.

Comment: I have already posted URL in the question. This is the page in which applet is used and its using Tiny class :http://javatester.org/enabled.html

Answer (score 0):

It was some priviledge issue. It started wokring after changing my windows profile setting.

Thanks,
Gunjan.